# High volume of data in Memory in azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, azure-worker-roles, worker

For faster calculation I am putting 4 List in memory. Each having 10,000 records. In sql server database total size of 40,000 records is 40 MB. Instead of fectching data from Database, I am putting all records in memory for longer time. Will it cause any issue?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? 4.0? 4.5?

Comment: Several dozen megabytes of memory will be easily available to you application.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is that your lists' underlying arrays may end up on the [large object heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx), and since they reference your cached data, it will be garbage collected more seldom than normal objects.

I can't imagine you'll run into trouble if you're not replacing the data very frequently, but it's something to keep an eye on. Also, .NET 4.5 has improvements in this area, so you'll want to try to run under that CLR.